# How to create a "play again" option with Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, restart

I am new to programming with Python. I have been working through a tutorial book that I found, and got the game up and running, but then decided I wanted to have a "Play Again?" option at the end. I can get the game to quit out with a press of the "n" key, but cannot work out how to get the game to restart.

Here is the code I think is giving the trouble:

```
#player reaches treasure
if player_rectangle.colliderect(treasure_rectangle):

#display text
    screen.blit(text,(screen_width/2-195,screen_height/2-25))
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_n:
            exit()

    elif event.key==pygame.K_y:


pygame.display.update()
```

I know something needs to go after the elif event, and I have tried all that I can think of. I tried to define the whole program, and call it but that stopped the whole thing running. I have looked around internet sites, but just cannot seem to come up with a answer.

Can some one help out in easy terms how to get the game to restart to the starting position when the y key is pressed? I know it has something to do with a loop, I just cannot place my finger on what.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear how your code is organized, so I'll be very general. Usually games are implemented with a "main loop" that handles all of the action. In "pseudo"-python:

```
def main_loop():
    while True:
        handle_next_action()
        draw_screen()

        if game_is_over():
            break
```

Before you start the loop, you usually do some setup to get the game state how you want it:

```
def main():
    setup()

    main_loop()

    shut_down()
```

Given those parts, you can reset the game by having the main loop code call `setup` again (it may need to be specifically designed to be runable more than once):

```
def main_loop():
    while True:
        handle_events()
        draw_screen()

        if game_is_over():
            if play_again():   # new code here!
                setup()
            else:
                break
```

You might want to split the `setup` code into two parts, one which only needs to be run when the program begins (to read configuration files and set up things like the window system), and a second that gets repeated for each new game (setting up the game's state).

Answer (score 0):

To restart a game you normally need to reset all variables to their initial value (e.g. number of lives, score, initial position, ...).

The best way is to put all initialisations inside a procedure:

```
def init():
    global score,lives     # use these global variables
    score=0
    lives=3

init()    # call init() to define and reset all values

while 1: # main loop
       ...
       elif event.key==pygame.K_y:
            init()            # restart the game
```

Comment: Thanks, both of you. That makes some sense. Ill give it a shot!